# How to get the active panel in jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jquery ui accordion plugin. How can I get the active panel in the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this selector :

```
 $( ".acc" ).accordion( "option", "active" );
```

Comment: The question was hot to get the active panel, *not* how to get the *index* of the active panel. So, how to get the active panel?

Comment: @theV0ID See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the question was more how to get the active panel div, and not just the index. Use this selector:

```
$("#accordion .ui-accordion-content")[$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active")];
```

or this one:

```
$("#accordion .ui-accordion-content-active");
```

Answer (score 1):

onclick  event add current index in hidden field,it's more easy to use.